# Keep unique rows in data.frame and aggregate the non-unique rows

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, unique, tidyr

I have a `data.frame` that is not unique for a subset of its columns and what I want to do is to obtain the unique part of the non-unique columns and corresponding aggregate (via `collapse`) the unique columns.

Here's an example:

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(v1=rnorm(5), v2=rnorm(5), v3=rnorm(5), id=paste0("id",1:5))

#Replicate a couple of rows adding different ids:
df <- df %>% rbind(df[sample(5,2,replace = F),] %>% dplyr::mutate(id=paste0("id",6:7)))

> df
          v1         v2       v3  id
1 -0.6264538 -0.8204684  1.5117812 id1
2  0.1836433  0.4874291  0.3898432 id2
3 -0.8356286  0.7383247 -0.6212406 id3
4  1.5952808  0.5757814 -2.2146999 id4
5  0.3295078 -0.3053884  1.1249309 id5
6 -0.8356286  0.7383247 -0.6212406 id6
7  0.3295078 -0.3053884  1.1249309 id7
```

Since rows 3 and 5 are replicated the resulting `data.frame` would be:

```
> data.frame(df[1:5,] %>% dplyr::select(-id),id=c("id1","id2","id3,id6","id4","id5,id7"))

          v1         v2       v3      id
1 -0.6264538 -0.8204684  1.5117812     id1
2  0.1836433  0.4874291  0.3898432     id2
3 -0.8356286  0.7383247 -0.6212406 id3,id6
4  1.5952808  0.5757814 -2.2146999     id4
5  0.3295078 -0.3053884  1.1249309 id5,id7
```

Is there a `dplyr` or `tidyr` way for doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df%>%
   group_by(v1,v2,v3)%>%
   summarise(id=toString(id))
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   v1, v2 [?]
      v1     v2     v3 id
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>         
1 -0.836  0.738 -0.621 id3, id6      
2 -0.626 -0.820  1.51  id1           
3  0.184  0.487  0.390 id2           
4  0.330 -0.305  1.12  id5, id7      
5  1.60   0.576 -2.21  id4           


df%>%
   group_by(v1,v2,v3)%>%
   summarise(id=toString(id))%>%data.frame()
          v1         v2         v3       id
1 -0.8356286  0.7383247 -0.6212406 id3, id6
2 -0.6264538 -0.8204684  1.5117812      id1
3  0.1836433  0.4874291  0.3898432      id2
4  0.3295078 -0.3053884  1.1249309 id5, id7
5  1.5952808  0.5757814 -2.2146999      id4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Onyambu. If I wanted to pass a vector of column names to  `group_by` (e.g. `c("v1","v2","v3")`), what do I do? I thought `group_by_(c("v1","v2","v3"))` would work but it's only returning `v1` and `id`.

Comment: well that is beyond the scope of this question. You will have to look at [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) to understand how to program with dplyr.

Answer (score 2):

Since I do think it's helpful here's the full solution that includes passing a string vector to `summarise`:

```
df %>%
  group_by_(.dots=c("v1","v2","v3")) %>%
  summarise(id=toString(id))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   v1, v2 [?]
          v1         v2         v3       id
       <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>    <chr>
1 -0.8356286  0.7383247 -0.6212406 id3, id6
2 -0.6264538 -0.8204684  1.5117812      id1
3  0.1836433  0.4874291  0.3898432      id2
4  0.3295078 -0.3053884  1.1249309 id5, id7
5  1.5952808  0.5757814 -2.2146999      id4
```